# jquery check if img is inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
 // w a s d
 
 $(document).ready(function(e){
  var keys = {};

  $(document).keydown(function(event){
    keys[event.which] = true;
  }).keyup(function(event){
    delete keys[event.which];
  });

  var $d = $("img");

  function gameLoop() {
    if (keys[68]) {     
        $d.css("left", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px"; });
    }
    else if (keys[65]) { 
        $d.css("left", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px"; });
    }
    if (keys[83]) {     
        $d.css("top", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px"; });
    }
    else if (keys[87]) {
        $d.css("top", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px"; });
    }
   
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
  }
  gameLoop();
    
  $(document).focus();
});

// arrows
 $(document).ready(function(e){
  var keys = {};

  $(document).keydown(function(event){
    keys[event.which] = true;
  }).keyup(function(event){
    delete keys[event.which];
  });

  var $d = $("img");

  function gameLoop() {
    if (keys[37]) {     
        $d.css("left", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px"; });
    }
    else if (keys[39]) { 
        $d.css("left", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px"; });
    }
    if (keys[40]) {     
        $d.css("top", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px"; });
    }
    else if (keys[38]) {
        $d.css("top", function(i,oldVal) { return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px"; });
    }
   
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
  }
  gameLoop();
    
  $(document).focus();
});


  $(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".goal:has(img)")){
        alert("yes");
    }
    });
```

```css
img {
position : absolute;
left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.goal{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Super Mario!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
        <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
        <div class="goal"></div>
        
        
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

 
</html>
```

I want an alert box that pops up when the Mario(img) is inside the goal(div). Thanks for the help. don't mind my js code it's just something random and I don't know if it's close to right, Thanks! 
Edit: the div is the green dot on the top right corner.

Comment: well. it seems to me that it's working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want an alert box that pops up when the Mario(img) is inside the
>   goal(div).

It seems, that you don't need to check if the element `img` is inside the `div` or not. What you want to do is just check if the coordinates of your *mario* `img` are within the range of the *goal* `div`.

Easiest would be to use [`element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), to obtain the `DOMRect` object which will hold the size and position of your elements. Use this to figure out if your *mario* is in the range of your *goal*.

Create a function to check the position every time keyboard navigation happens. Like this:

```
function checkMario() { 
  var goalPost = $('.goal')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var mario = $('#mario')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if ((goalPost.left - mario.left) < 60) {
      $('#result').text('yesssss');
    } else {
      $('#result').text('no yet');
    }
}
```

**Example Snippet:**

In this example, I have kept it simple to simply calculate if the `left` position is within the range of the `div`. You will then need to refine it further to check for all sides.

Try using your keyboard left/right keys to move the *mario* in to the *goal*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var keys = {};

  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    keys[event.which] = true;
  }).keyup(function(event) {
    delete keys[event.which];
  });

  var $d = $("img");

  function gameLoop() {
    if (keys[68]) {
      $d.css("left", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px";
      });
    } else if (keys[65]) {
      $d.css("left", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px";
      });
    }
    if (keys[83]) {
      $d.css("top", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px";
      });
    } else if (keys[87]) {
      $d.css("top", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px";
      });
    }

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
  }
  gameLoop();

  $(document).focus();
});

// arrows
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var keys = {};

  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    keys[event.which] = true;
  }).keyup(function(event) {
    delete keys[event.which];
  });

  var $d = $("img");

  function gameLoop() {
    if (keys[37]) {
      $d.css("left", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px";
      });
      checkMario();
    } else if (keys[39]) {
      $d.css("left", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px";
      });
      checkMario();
    }
    if (keys[40]) {
      $d.css("top", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) + 5 + "px";
      });
      checkMario();
    } else if (keys[38]) {
      $d.css("top", function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal) - 5 + "px";
      });
      checkMario();
    }
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
  }
  gameLoop();

  $(document).focus();
});


function checkMario() { 
  var goalPost = $('.goal')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var mario = $('#mario')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    if ((goalPost.left - mario.left) < 60) {
      $('#result').text('yesssss');
    } else {
      $('#result').text('no yet');
    }
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; width: 60px;
}
.goal {
  width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: green; float: right;
}
p { margin-top: 64px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='mario'  src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg" />
<div class="goal"></div>
<br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thanks it works but I'm having a hard time fixing it with the top and bottom part.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `$(".goal").find("img").length > 0`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".goal").find("img").length > 0) {
    alert("yes");
  } else { alert( "no" ); }
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.goal {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Super Mario!</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />

</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg" />
  <div class="goal"></div>


</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: If OP checking only for direct children, this gets failed :)

Comment: @ANS No, it prints 'yes' if I change markup to `<div class="goal">
      <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg" />
</div>
`

Comment: And also gives true when mark up is 

`<div class="goal"> <div><img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein‌​/mario.jpg" /> </div></div>`

Comment: @ANS that is right. But that is what OP has asked for `I want an alert box that pops up when the Mario(img) is inside the goal(div)` OP hasn't mentioned if img has to be only direct descendant of div.

Answer (score 1):

Your question have 2 cases.

Image inside of div at any level, children and it's children too. In that case,

```
if ($(".goal").find('img').length) {
        // yes
    }
```

If you want to check only children and not children of children you can try

```
if($(.goal).find('> img').length) {
   // yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector and check the length of the result: `$(".goal img").length`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".goal img").length) {
    alert("yes");
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.goal {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Super Mario!</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />

</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg" />
  <div class="goal">
      <img>
  </div>


</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("img").closest('.goal').length){
        alert("yes");
    }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the efforts, but simply saying "try this" is not a good approach. You should give a good explanation for why to try this / or why this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check for image tag  `length` using `find` .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('.goal').find('img').length >0 )  
  alert("yes");
else
  alert("no");  
    });
```

```css
img {
position : absolute;
left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.goal{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Super Mario!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
        <img src="http://i1061.photobucket.com/albums/t480/ericqweinstein/mario.jpg"/>
        <div class="goal"></div>
        
        
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

 
</html>
```